# Script for inserting an item into a different table in Windows Azure

Tags: javascript, sql, windows, azure

I've just started developing with Windows Azure. So far so good but I'm stuck with a very basic question: How to insert an item into a different table from a mobile services script? The code I have found on Windows Azure blogs doesn't seem to work as advertised:

```
function insert(item, user, request) {

    var currentTable = tables.getTable('current'); // table for this script
    var otherTable = tables.getTable('other'); // another table within the same db

    var test = "1234";
    request.execute(); // inserts the item in currentTable

    // DOESN'T WORK: returns an Internal Server Error
    otherTable.insert(test, {
                        success: function()
                        {

                        }
    });
}
```

Any idea of what I am doing wrong or where I could find some help on the syntax to use? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the answer on another StackOverFlow Post that had never come up before, typical...
The thing I was doing wrong was not providing the name of the column to update. so instead of having:

```
var test = "1234";
// DOESN'T WORK because no column is declared
otherTable.insert(test, {
                    success: function()
                    {

                    }
});
```

I should have had:

```
var test = {code : "1234"};
// WORKS because the script knows in what column to store the data 
// (here the column is called "code")
otherTable.insert(test, {
                    success: function()
                    {

                    }
});
```

So to give the entire right code:

```
function insert(item, user, request) {

    var currentTable = tables.getTable('current'); // table for this script
    var otherTable = tables.getTable('other'); // another table within the same db

    var test = {code: "1234"};
    request.execute(); // inserts the item in currentTable

    otherTable.insert(test, {
                    success: function()
                    {

                    }
    }); // inserts test in the code column in otherTable
}
```